# Submit button does nothing

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a submit button in a form and use PHP for scripting to email the form. When the button is pressed nothing happens, not even showing the PHP code like when PHP isn't installed. I have tested other simple mailing forms on machine and they show the code. This one does nothing.

HTML Code:

```
<form name="apply" method="post" action="mail.php">                 
<font class="error-message"></font>
    <div class="form-content">
        <div class="left-label">
            <label>First and Last name:</label>
            <label>School type:</label>
            <label>Practice name:</label>
            <label class="address">Address:</label>
    <label class="address2">Address (cont):</label>
    <label class="zip">Zip Code:</label>
    <label class="city">City:</label>
            <label>Website:</label>
            <label>Email:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right-fields">                          
            <input type="text" name="fist-last-name" placeholder="First & Last name" title="Please enter First & Last name." />
            <select name="select-school">
                <option>--select--</option>
                <option>Dental Assistant School</option>
                <option>Medical Assistant School</option>
                <option>Pharmacy Technician School</option>
                <!-- <option>Personal Trainer School</option> -->
                <option>Other School</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="practice-name" placeholder="Practice name" title="Please enter your practice name." />
            <textarea name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" title="Please enter address1"></textarea>
            <textarea name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" title="Please enter address2"></textarea>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" title="Please enter your zipcode." /><br>
            <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" title="Please enter the city where you live." />
            <input type="text" name="website-address" placeholder="Website" title="Please enter your website address." />
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" title="Please enter your email address." />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

PHP code, `mail.php`:

```
<?php

$fist_last_name     = $_POST["fist-last-name"];

$school_type        = $_POST["select-school"];

$practice_name      = $_POST["practice-name"];

$address1           = $_POST["address1"];

$address2           = $_POST["address2"];

$zipcode            = $_POST["zipcode"];

$city               = $_POST["city"];

$website            = $_POST["website-address"];

$email              = $_POST["email"];


$body   = " <table>

                <tr><th>First Last name:</th><td>".$fist_last_name."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>School type:</th><td>".$school_type."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>Practice name:</th><td>".$practice_name."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>address1:</th><td>".$address1."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>address2:</th><td>".$address2."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>Zipcode:</th><td>".$zipcode."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>City:</th><td>".$city."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>Website:</th><td>".$website."</td></tr>

                <tr><th>Email:</th><td>".$email."</td></tr>

            </table>";

mail('emailaddress@domain.com','No Reply',$body,"From: noreply@domain.com");

?>
```

This is the JavaScript for the form validation:

```
/* Form validation */

$("form[name='apply']").submit(function(){
    var error = true;
    var text_fields = ["fist-last-name", "practice-name", "zipcode", "city", "website-address", "email"];
    $.each(text_fields,function(key,value){
        if(!$.trim($("input[name='"+value+"']").val()) == "") {
            $("input[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
        }
        else{
            $("input[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
            error = false;
        }
    });
    if($("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").val() == "--select--") {
        $("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
        error = false;
    }
    else {
        $("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
    }
    var textarea_fields = ["address1", "address2"];
    $.each(textarea_fields,function(key,value){
        if(!$.trim($("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").val()) == "" ) {
            $("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
        }
        else {
            $("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
            error = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(error);
    if(error == true) {
        $.post('mail.php',$("form[name='apply']").serialize(),function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("form[name='apply'] input[type='text'], form[name='apply'] textarea").blur(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
        $(".error-message").text($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
        $(".error-message").text('');
    }
});
$("form[name='apply'] input[type='text'], form[name='apply'] textarea").bind("keydown",function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
        $(".error-message").text($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
    }
});
```

The error occurs in this code:

```
$("form[name='apply']").submit(function(){
    var error = true;
    var text_fields = ["fist-last-name", "practice-name", "zipcode", "city", "website-address", "email"];
    $.each(text_fields,function(key,value){
        if(!$.trim($("input[name='"+value+"']").val()) == "") {
            $("input[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
        }
        else{
            $("input[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
            error = false;
        }
    });
    if($("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").val() == "--select--") {
        $("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
        error = false;
    }
    else {
        $("form[name='apply'] select[name='select-school']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
    }
    var textarea_fields = ["address1", "address2"];
    $.each(textarea_fields,function(key,value){
        if(!$.trim($("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").val()) == "" ) {
            $("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': '#ccc'});
        }
        else {
            $("form[name='apply'] textarea[name='"+value+"']").css({'border-color': 'red'});
            error = false;
        }
    });
    console.log(error);
    if(error == true) {
        $.post('mail.php',$("form[name='apply']").serialize(),function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: does it actually submit?

Comment: Yeah, what happens WHEN you click the submit button? Does the URL change to mail.php?

Comment: No, it does nothing. Just stays on the same page. The email is never sent, page is never posted, nothing.

Comment: The code as posted here does try to load a "mail.php", so that part is OK. The problem is in your "mail.php" right? Can you debug that doing `print_r($_POST)` or something?

Comment: Is there any external or inline javascript which could be adding code the `onsubmit` event and preventing the submit?

Comment: @BillPalanski Strange. You don't have other things that can interfere, like a `form` nested within another `form`, javascript handlers for the inputs, etc?

Comment: OF of course you stay on the same page: you're posting the form using ajax, and the form.submit event returns false (in jQuery, this is the same as `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()`). the mail might not be sent because your php.ini isn't set correctly, read the php mail manual for that

Comment: This is off topic, but there is a lot of code in your question. In the future try to post the minimum amount of code which reproduces the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Javascript is stopping the form from submitting. When you `return false` in a form's `submit` event, it prevents the form being submitted.

I think you want to return the `error` variable which seems to be a boolean to indicate a validation error.

Try:

```
$("form[name='apply']").submit(function(){

    .... JS code ....
    return error;
});
```

Using that, if there are no validation errors, the form will submit. Also your `error` boolean is slightly misleading, it would be more logical if `error` is true then there is a validation error, but you have it reversed - won't make any difference to the actual code execution, just a readability point.

Comment: TY! That worked perfectly. Knew it was something simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(isset($_POST['practice-name'])){ die('values posted'); }else{ die('nothing was posted'}` and let us know what it does.

Comment: You will be able to, one day.

Comment: I can only comment on my own posts, like this one. I've already solved another question that was asked here, and there I COULD add comments ...

Comment: On top of your mail.php file, just under `<?php`                     And make sure your mail.php is in the same folder as your HTML file.

Comment: Put that in and still does nothing. Mail.php is in same folder as the html file.

Comment: Can you do the same again but disable javascript in your browser this time?

Comment: Done and now it posts and goes to mail.php and shows code since I don't have php installed. So it's in JavaScript :(

Comment: Try commenting out all but one section of code at a time, so you'll get an idea of where the error is located.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try commenting out everything in mail.php and doing something really simple like:

```
<?php echo "This works!"; ?>
```

Just to see if it actually submits to the page. If it does, the problem would be with the 'post' variables or the input form. Try making a new html page with an input form to mail.php but with nothing else other than the textboxes and submit button. If it submits and mail.php receives all the data, the problem would have to do with something other than the files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Commented everything out and still did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that the form does not get submitted at all - and I tested the code and it does submit the way it is - **then you must have some JavaScript function or event listener that stops the form from being submitted**.

Your HTML works and form submit does tell browser to submit the form. This can't be a PHP problem, since if submit does not even happen then PHP plays no role in this if the form itself is displayed correctly.

Comment: So the HTML and php are fine? Let me look over the JS again.

Comment: Yeah HTML is certainly fine, did not look at PHP since it is not important at the moment (PHP would only be important if the form would actually submit to that URL - which id does not).

Form validation is rather complicated there, so I have no time to take a look at it right away, but try to make a test and submit the form -without form validation-. Does it now submit?